# Hidden table row colspan fails to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with each row having 4 `td` cells. It has a row hidden with one `td colspan="4"` inside it.

When I show the hidden row it ignores the `colspan="4"` - is this because it's hidden first of all?

Is there anyway around this?

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden" id="123">
    <td colspan="4">full width</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" onclick="showRow(); return false;">click me</a>
```

Javascript

```
function showRow(){
  el = document.getElementById('123');
  el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqk8puLz/)

Comment: technically a table row is not a block.

Comment: working well for me on chrome, but try 'table-row' instead of 'block'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a block, it is a table row

```
el.style.display = 'table-row';
```

It would be better to just remove the `hidden` class.

```
el.classList.remove("hidden");  //FYI, not all browsers support classList
```

Comment: God damn css! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

In you Javascript, change

```
el.style.display = 'block';
```

to

```
el.style.display = 'table-row';
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqk8puLz/1/)